# KVO on Local Notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification, key-value-observing, uiapplication

I'm updating a button based on if I have local notifications set on my iOS app. I'd like to do this with KVO, as there are various ways notifications can be set so I won't be easily able to track when a change is made to the local notifications otherwise.

I'm setting it up like this:

```
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] addObserver:self
                                        forKeyPath:@"scheduleLocalNotifications"
                                           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial
                                           context:NULL];
```

but the problem is, apart from the initial call I'm not getting anything come through into my observer method

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

Am I doing something wrong in my addObserver method or is there another way I can be notified of my scheduled local notifications?

Answer (score 1):

1. The property's name is `scheduledLocalNotifications` (you missed the d).
2. This property is not KVO compliant. You can't reliably use KVO to observe changes.